# Kotlin continue inside a map operation

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to transform a list with a series of filter and map calls. The filter logic is again used in map call, and I want to avoid that duplicate call. I think the code sums it up well:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    multipleCalls()
    wontCompile()
}

fun multipleCalls(){
    val arr = intArrayOf(1,2,3)
    val list = arr.filter{
        it.heavyLogic() != null
    }.map{
        it.heavyLogic()    //heavyLogic() called again
    }
    print(list)
}

fun wontCompile(){
    val arr = intArrayOf(1,2,3)
    val list = arr.map{
        val str = it.heavyLogic()
        if(str == null) continue //break and continue are only allowed inside a loop
        else str
    }
    print(list)
}
```

Is there an equivalent of break/continue inside a map, that can fix `wontCompile()` ?

I realize I can also have `map` return `null`s, thereby making `list` of type `List<String?>` - and then `filter` by `null`. But that still iterates the list twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [mapNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html).

```
inline fun <T, R : Any> Array<out T>.mapNotNull(
    transform: (T) -> R?
): List<R> (source)
```

> I realize I can also have map return nulls, thereby making list of
>   type List - and then filter by null. But that still iterates
>   the list twice.

By using `mapNotNull` the list will only need to be iterated once, null items are ignored during that time.

```
/**
 * Applies the given [transform] function to each element in the original collection
 * and appends only the non-null results to the given [destination].
 */
public inline fun <T, R : Any, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<T>.mapNotNullTo(destination: C, transform: (T) -> R?): C {
    forEach { element -> transform(element)?.let { destination.add(it) } }
    return destination
}
```

In your code you can do like :

```
val list = arr.mapNotNull{
    it.heavyLogic()
}
```

You can also check about [filterNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html).

Comment: Still not clear. How do I trigger continue in this iteration? For example you have to increment other property if heavyLogic == null